# Access form data node js

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, form-data, body-parser

I am building API which accepts form data(variable or image). I am passing the following
[image]

I am just rendering the req as it is and getting

```
{
    "------WebKitFormBoundarykjCufNDj9Nu9UePk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name": "\"attachment_type_id\"\r\n\r\n0\r\n
    ------WebKitFormBoundarykjCufNDj9Nu9UePk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"firstName\"\r\n\r\nImrn\r\n
    ------WebKitFormBoundarykjCufNDj9Nu9UePk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"lastName\"\r\n\r\nAhmd\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykjCufNDj9Nu9UePk--\r\n"
}
```

If I render `req.body.attachment_type_id`, I get blank response.
How can I get data value `attachment_type_id`? I have to check `attachment_type_id` before uploading the image.

Comment: Why do you render the form data value? Typically you would use the value to save the data somewhere.

Comment: I have to use data value to form query.

Comment: Okay, but why do you need to render it? What happens if you log `req.body.firstName` in `node`? Is the value not posted to the server?

Comment: I get undefined on server. I don't want to render i just want the data value to form query. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`form-data` in Postman is mostly used to send large binary data. If you want to simulate sending text from a web form, you should use `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I agree with you, actually i am sending an image and a variable as attachment type.

Comment: Ok. [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is a great middleware for handling `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 1):

Add body-parser as a middleware to your express app before defining routes.

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

body-parser populates request data in req.body

Make sure to add correct headers to your request 
"key" : Content-Type
"value" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"